# Java RXTX library change pins

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

I have to communicate with a device from serial port. I am using Java and RXTX library and working on Ubuntu. However, I have a problem:

When I get the related serial port's CommPortIdentifier, RXTX library sets all serial port pins(RTS, CTS, DTR, DCD etc.) to high(true) for a short time and then sets the pins to low(false). I understood this via monitoring serial port pins with another program. The device which I have to communicate collapses because it waits data while RTS pin is high(true). I have to restart the device after RXTX library completed its work in order to communicate with it.

So, here is my question(s):

Can I prevent this RXTX library situation? How should I use the RXTX library to control the serial port? I do not want changing pins out of my information. 
Or is there any suggestion about another serial port library for Java which worths to try?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. Now, I am using JSSC for serial port operations. It sets all serial port pins to high while opening the serial port and does not change pins anymore out of my information.